# Stop scroll after scrollTop >= scrollHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this custom `<select>`.

Inside the `.select_list` I have an `ul` with `height:300px;` and `overflow:hidden;`
When I hover the buttons inside the `.select_list` the `<ul>` is scrolling up or down.

My problem is that when I hover for example the 'Scroll down' button, the ul.scrollTop() its still increasing even if the scrollTop its over the scrollHeight.

After that if I'm scrolling top I have to wait a couple of miliseconds to scroll up again.

Can someone explain or help to stop the scrolling when the ul is scrolled to maximum?

Here is the JSbin:

http://jsbin.com/wupavameze/edit?css,js,output

```
    $up.on('mouseover', function() {
            doScroll(-offset);
        })
        .on('mouseout', function() {
            stopScroll();
        });


    $down.on('mouseover', function() {
            doScroll(offset);
        })
        .on('mouseout', function() {
            stopScroll();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In doScroll function use the current value of scrollTop.
Below is the modified function.

```
function doScroll(v) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $list.scrollTop($list.scrollTop() + v);
    }, 30);
}
```